# Vim tab spacing after enter (new line)

Tags: vim

I've this tab spacing configuration:

```
set autoindent
set smartindent
set expandtab tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 smarttab softtabstop=4
```

and at the end of configuration, I put this:

```
autocmd FileType javascript,jade,json set shiftwidth=2 tabstop=2 softtabstop=2
```

The 2 spaces tab works just fine. But, if I type enter (new line), it became 4 spaces. Here is the example:

```
     var Post = orm.define('Post', {       
       title: sequelize.STRING,      
       content: sequelize.STRING,
         | /* wrong spaces */
     });
```

But if I use 4 tab spaces, it also use 4 spaces after enter.

I can't figure out what's the problem.

### EDIT:

It ONLY happened when I write object-literal in a javascript callback function (like the code example above). It works fine with general code statement and in json object-literal. Here is the example:

```
    /* the 2 spaces works fine*/
    app.set('port', 3000);
    app.use(express.bodyParser());

    /* also works fine here */
    var config = {
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 5432
    }
```

Comment: Smartindent is generally useless: you can safely remove it from your config.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.. Did you find a working solution?

Comment: I know I'm 8 years late, I just wanted to mention that once you type the object property and the `:` the extra spaces will go away.

Answer (score 21):

Please try using the following:

```
set smartindent
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set expandtab
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, this problem only happened when I was trying to write object literal in javascript callback function. It works fine with writing general code statement. I'll edit the question.

Comment: I create ~/.vimrc is the content above. I hope this can help.

Comment: The guy is asking about indenting and you put completely unrelated settings (like number, clipboard) into the answer?

Comment: Which of the settings in the answer is responsible for fixing the issue described in the question?

Answer (score 2):

I found this question trying to understand why the size of my tab char is different depending of autoidentation using ENTER key () or using the TAB key.
This link helped me to solve my problem after read older answers.
https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/99ylz8/confused_about_the_difference_between_tabstop_and/

To solve the differences between these indentation sizes I put in my `$HOME/.vimrc`:

```
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
```

I realize with these two settings `tabstop` is the size when I press TAB on keyboard and `shiftwidth` is the size when I press ENTER on keyboard.